# D's command line behavior for stdin/stdout

Tags: d

Sample code:

```
import std.stdio;

int main()
{
    int line = 0;
    while (line != 1)
    {
        stdout.writef("Enter num 1: ");
        stdin.readf(" %d ", &line);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

When this program is run from the command line, you'd expect to simply enter the number 1 and then have the program quit. This doesn't happen when this program is compiled with the D compiler. I'm unsure why, unless it has to to with having stdin and stdout be contained in separate threads where stdin feeds input to the stdout bucket, and then on the next input, stdout takes from what it's fed and acts on it.

Could someone please explain this behavior?
I'm running dmd version 2.069.1

Command line output:

```
sample@sample:~$ ./sample
Enter num 1: 1
x
sample@sample:~$
```

Additional example:

```
import std.stdio;

int main()
{
    int line = 0;
    while (line != 1)
    {
        stdout.writef("Wrong, echo %d, enter num 1: ", line);
        stdin.readf(" %d ", &line);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Command line:

```
sample@sample:~$ ./sample
Wrong, echo 0, enter num 1: 2
3
Wrong, echo 2, enter num 1: 4
Wrong, echo 3, enter num 1: 5
Wrong, echo 4, enter num 1: 6
Wrong, echo 5, enter num 1: 7
Wrong, echo 6, enter num 1: 8
Wrong, echo 7, enter num 1: 9
Wrong, echo 8, enter num 1: 1
Wrong, echo 9, enter num 1: 1
sample@sample:~$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You problem is space char after %d. This code works fine:

```
import std.stdio;

int main()
{
    int line = 0;
    while (line != 1)
    {
        writef("Enter num 1: ");
        readf(" %d", &line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now I feel dumb :(, thanks for pointing a simple logic error out